# how to get count total occurance from different tables in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have three different tables for 3 different activities. The common field is user_id.

Performance:

```
id | user_id | date  | mark    
1  | 123     |  xx   |  20
2  | 456     |  xx   |  10
3  | 789     |  xx   |  5
4  | 123     |  xx   |  10
5  | 456     |  xx   |  10
6  | 789     |  xx   |  5
```

Internal Activities:

```
id | user_id | date  | mark    
1  | 123     |  xx   |  20
2  | 456     |  xx   |  10
3  | 789     |  xx   |  5
4  | 123     |  xx   |  10
5  | 456     |  xx   |  10
6  | 789     |  xx   |  5
```

Other Activities :

```
id | user_id | date  | mark    
1  | 123     |  xx   |  20
2  | 456     |  xx   |  10
3  | 789     |  xx   |  5
4  | 123     |  xx   |  10
5  | 456     |  xx   |  10
6  | 789     |  xx   |  5
```

How to fetch each user marks in all the 3 tables for and sort it in DESC. result should be like

```
id | user_id |  mark    
1  | 123     |   90
2  | 456     |   60
3  | 789     |   30
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may perform a `UNION` of all 3 tables and then apply `GROUP BY` on the result.

Comment: How you calculated mark 30 for user_id 123?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: actually i have mistyped the total. how i have edited the result table. i am new to mysql. help me with the exact query on UNION and GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, SUM(p.mark) FROM Performance p 
LEFT JOIN Internal Activities ia ON p.id=ia.id
LEFT JOIN Other Activities oa ON ia.id=oa.id 
GROUP BY p.user_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT tmp.ID,tmp.USER_ID,tmp.SUM(mark) 
FROM 
(select * from Performance

union all

select * from Internal_Activities

union all 

select * from Other_Activities
) as tmp
group by tmp.USER_ID
```

Note :- Why are you keeping 3 separate table with same schema ,cant you make it one ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 p.id
,p.user_id
,@performance:=p.mark AS performance
,@other_activities:=oa.mark AS other_activities
,@internal_activities:=ia.mark AS internal_activities
,@total_mark:=@performance+@other_activities+@internal_activities AS total_mark
FROM
table1 p
LEFT JOIN table2 ia
USING(user_id)
LEFT JOIN table2 oa
USING(user_id)
```